# Import entire directory of images into array - React

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Im new to react

I created my react project using create-react-app.

I need the same functionality as `import logo from './logo.png';`but for a directory.

something like `import * as Images from './images/';` and Images would be an array.

I found some solutions for `webpack` but they obviously don't work, is this possible in my situation?

for context here is how i want to use the images. Currently, they are hardcoded into this.state.images[]

```
const style = {
      //overflowY: "scroll",
      height: 5000,
      width: "100%",
      backgroudImage: `url(${this.state.images[this.state.index]})`,
      backgroundPosition: "center",
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
    };
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Create a const to save images that you needed like

```
export const Images =  [
  '/assets/images/1.png', 
  '/assets/images/2.png',  
  '/assets/images/3.png'
];
```

Then in your components, import that const and render like

import { Images } from './../../utils/Image'

```
<React.Fragment>
{
   Images.map((item, index) =>  {
      return <div 
                key={index} 
                style={{
                  //overflowY: "scroll",
                  height: 5000,
                  width: "100%",
                  backgroundImage: `url(${item})`,
                  backgroundPosition: "center",
                  backgroundSize: "cover",
                  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"}}>
            </div>
   })
}
</React.Fragment>
```

If you set the style as className and then pass the image dynamic to the context

```
<React.Fragment>
{
    Images.map((item, index) =>  {
       return <div 
                  key={index} 
                  className='image-container'
                  style={{backgroundImage: `url(${item})`}}>
              </div>
  })
}
</React.Fragment>
```

If you are going for update the webpack, then please install the url-loader and file-loader

```
npm install url-loader file-loader --save-dev
```

then update the webpack config as

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
},
```